# can't push a folder in existing repo with folders

Tags: git, github

I have a `main_project` which contain `project1`,`project2`,`project3`. I want to add `project4` files into, I've run these commands, it creates the folder but as an empty folder :

```
git pull
# add the project4
git add .
git commit -m "test"
git push
```

Comment: Is everything in project 4 being ignored do to your .gitignore?

Comment: What does `git status` show?

Comment: What happens after you do the above commands? Do the folders have any files or are they empty? Note that [git cannot track empty folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it push the main_project and the project4 is empty (but in my local machine its not empty)

Comment: Run `git status` and update your question to include the output of `git status`

Comment: @StephenNewell when i run `git status` it show "nothing to commit" but if i run `git init` , `git add .` , `git commit -m "test" ` on project4 and execute `git status` again it show me that there is something to commit when i commit it and push it, it still an empty folder

Comment: Do you have a `.gitignore` file?

Answer (score 0):

If the project4 itself has a `.git` subfolder, that would means:

- it is a Git repo,
- a `git add .` from the parent project would only record a gitlink (special entry in the index), not the actual folder content.

If you don't need `project4` folder history, simply remove the `.git` subfolder.

If you do need, consider referencing `project4` through [submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).